# Node-Webkit SaveAs File Dialog only triggers for unique file names?

Tags: javascript, node-webkit

On the Node-Webkit web site (https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/File-dialogs) it says to use the `<Input type="file">` to bring up a file picker dialog, and then listen for the `change` event to get the path and filename selected or specified.

This works fine the first time when I specify or select a file name, but if I bring up the file picker again and use the SAME file name, the `change` event doesn't get fired! Only if I change the filename in the selector dialog does the change event fire. Below is an example:

```
<input id="export_file" type="file" nwsaveas style="display:none" nwworkingdir=""/>
```

```
<script>

  var chooser = jQuery("#export_file");

  chooser.change(function(evt) 
  {
     alert(jQuery(this).val());
  });

  chooser.trigger('click'); 

</script>
```

Does anyone know a way to always fire an event after the user selects a file from the file picker (regardless if the file was previously picked or defined)?

Thanks.

Comment: I've updated my example with all the lines of code in my html5/js file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your "handler" only gets called when the  tag sees a change, you could reset it (after doing your handling -- alert call, in this case) so that every time is like the first time. If you "reset" the input tag, however, that fires a change event, so you need to (1)remove the change event listener, (2)reset the input tag to undefined and (3) restore the change event listener.
Using the new node-webkit 0.7.0 File and Filelist constructors -- this will only work with v0.7.0 -- the following code should work.

```
<script>

  var chooser = jQuery("#export_file");

  function fileHandler (evt) {

    alert(jQuery(this).val());

    var f = new File('',''); 
    var files = new FileList(); 
    files.append(f); 
    chooser.unbind('change'); 
    document.getElementById('export_file').files = files; 
    chooser.change(fileHandler);
  }

  chooser.change(fileHandler);
  chooser.trigger('click'); 

</script>
```

Jonathan

"Windows Desktop App Creation with node-webkit"

Comment: Great! Thank you for that bit of coding. I gave it a try, and it worked like a charm. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more of your code, I'll hazard a guess and suggest :

```
jQuery('#export_file').trigger('change');
```

Hope this helps,

Jonathan

"Windows App Creation with node-webkit"

Comment: I've updated my posting with all my coding. I'm not sure how adding the .trigger() listener will help my situation-- it seems the change event doesn't get fired if the file dialog from the <INPUT> tag doesn't see a *change* in file name selected from the previously selected file name.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work by just clearing the files object on the input.  Something like:

```
<input id="save" type="file" nwsaveas="graphdata.csv" style="display:none" accept=".csv"/>
```

and

```
$('#save').on('change', function (e) {
    console.log(this.value);

    this.files.clear();
});
```